# Kotlin Spring @Value for custom data class

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-el

I want to be able to do something like the following:

```yaml
#application.yml

servers:
  foo:
    name: "Foo"
    url: "http://localhost:8080/foo"
    description: "Foo foo"
  bar:
    name: "Bar"
    url: "http://localhost:8080/bar"
    description: "Bar bar"
```

```kotlin
data class Server (
   val name : String,
   val url : String,
   val description : String
)
```

Then somewhere in the code

```kotlin
@Service
class LookupService (
   @Value ("\${servers.foo}")
   val fooServer : Server,

   @Value ("\${servers.bar}")
   val barServer : Server
) {
// do stuff
}
```

When I try it currently I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'servers.bar' in value "${servers.bar}"` on starting up the app.

Is there a simple way to do this without specifically doing an `@Value` on each property?

Comment: you can use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation but it still require you to define the field variables, and then you can inject it to your service and use it there, here is the reference link to the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: about your error, is there any reason why you put backslash "\" character right before the spring binding properties?

Comment: @Aleson the backslash is required, otherwise Kotlin try to solve the variable immediately. Because Kotlin string interpolation uses the same syntax as Spel variables : ${locally.accessible.variable.name}

Comment: @Aleson is right, you have to annotate your data class with `@ConfigurationProperties`, but also with `@ConstructorBinding`. I've got a simple exemple in [this example class](https://github.com/alexismanin/get-started-spring-boot/blob/3bad57875a1a86873f567bccd81d301af9db9ba5/src/main/kotlin/fr/amanin/demos/hellospringboot/HelloSpringBootApplication.kt)

Comment: Ok, the use-case is trickier than I thought. Do you want the list of servers to be dynamic (i.e. you want to be capable to add a `myServer` entry without changing source code), or static ? Because I could provide two slightly different solutions according to your use-case.

Comment: @amanin It's statically set. I don't have any plans to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `@Value` is only capable of handling a "leaf" property, i.e. a property with a single value, not a property with children.

This is my understanding of [type-safe configuration properties documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties).

What you can do in your case is prepare a `Servers` structure that will contain map your entire configuration tree up to a certain point. In your case, you can create it with `foo` and `bar` attributes of type `Server`.

For it to fully work, you need to put 3 annotations in your code:

1. `@EnableConfigurationProperties(Servers::class)` on a configuration class to activate support of type-safe configuration for the servers
2. `@ConfigurationProperties("servers") on` Servers`class, to tell Spring that Servers should be filled with data extracted from properties with`servers` prefix
3. `@ConstructorBinding` on `Servers` class, to tell Spring it is immutable, and values must be injected using constructor.

You will find a working minimal example below:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Servers::class)
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

data class Server(val name: String, val url: URL, val description: String)

@ConfigurationProperties("servers")
@ConstructorBinding
data class Servers(val foo: Server, val bar: Server)

@Service
class LookupService(servers : Servers) {
    val foo = servers.foo
    val bar = servers.bar

    init {
        println(foo)
        println(bar)
    }
}
```

When started, the example app prints injected configuration:

```
Server(name=Foo, url=http://localhost:8080/foo, description=Foo foo)
Server(name=Bar, url=http://localhost:8080/bar, description=Bar bar)
```